# Webpack Normal Module Replacement for branding

Tags: webpack

I'm working on a brandable product and I have following folder structure:

```
-> default js folder
-> brands folder
----> a brand
--------> js
------------> brand specific js file
```

I want to override a brand specific Javascript file with a default file (both of files have same name - for example I have a `profile.js` file for each folder) while bundling is in progress on Webpack. I found a way which is Normal Module Replacement but I couldn't realize it.

How can I do it? Can someone share an example Webpack config please?

Comment: From my understanding you will need to bundle each brands separately, so How about simply using `resolve.alias` and pass the brand name as environment variables?

Comment: If it will work, solution is not important at this time. So how can I do it @EvanSebastian?

Comment: Also, I want to highlight a point: I have default js files for all of the brands. But if it's needed I should override the default one for a brand.

Comment: Ok, I'll write it in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use resolve alias to override resolving of a file based on configuration (in this case, brand name or fallback to default). Here is a simple example:

```
const path = require('path');
const brand = process.env.BRAND;

// Then add this to your Webpack config
{
 ...
 resolve: {
   alias: {
     brand: brand
        ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', brand)
        : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'defaultDirectory'), 'profile.js')
   }
 }
}
```

Afterwards, when you need to bundle for a certain brand, just set `BRAND=somebrand` in the environment variable. Whenever you do `import Profile from 'brand/profile'` and `import Contact from 'brand/contact'`, it will resolve to `./src/somebrand/profile.js` and `./src/somebrand/contact.js`, respectively.  It will fallback to default `./src/defaultDirectory/profile.js` and `./src/defaultDirectory/contact.js` if BRAND is not defined.

You can see more usage in [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias)

Comment: Thanks for your help Evan, but I don't know which file is needed to override, it can be another file like `posts.js` What about it? Is there a generic way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, drop the $ and change it to something like `brands`. Then all relative imports will be overriden, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I would add that there is a plugin for **path overriding in Webpack**: [path-override-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jamiehill/path-override-webpack-plugin). They explicitly mention **skinning** as the main purpose for using it. It allows you to define an override path and the plugin will look for all instances of a file in the override directory falling back to the default one.

In your case, you would simply specify an override like this:

```js
// webpack.config.js
import PathOverridePlugin from 'path-override-webpack-plugin'

const webpackConfig = {
    plugins: [
        new PathOverridePlugin(/whitelabel/, 'brandname')
    ]
}
```

Of course, you should then use proper `regexp` and `string` values in place of `whitelabel` and `brandname`, according to your project's need.

I still like the chosen answer, but this might be a cleaner solution in some cases.